# ClassCastException confusion cannot find error

Tags: java, classcastexception

Can someone please explain to me why e will throw a ClassCastException at runtime?
[Image of answer I found online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWs3N.png)

Comment: Please add you code, not an image of it. also, if you're going to add an image, please do so on the site, and not a link to said image

Comment: Because not all `Mammal`s are `Dog`s?

Comment: your reverse casting is crashing because not all Mammals are Dogs...

Answer (score 0):

Here `Dog` is a subclass of `Mammal`. If you create an object of `Dog`. You can cast it into a `Mammal`, because the dog is also a `Mammal`.

But if you create an object of `Mammal`, you cannot convert(cast) it to `Dog` because all dogs are not necessarily `Mammal`.

Comment: Thanks bro, could you tell me why the answer for B is b. I don't understand if it is just because fido was not instantiated or not?

Comment: It is the similar case. A `Mammal` cannot be converted(assigned) to a `Dog`. And If my answer solver your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote the answer.